# How to get extra attributes of a user in user pool in AWS Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using amazon-cognito-identity-js to authenticate my user pool users.And after authenticating it's passing access token, id token and refresh token.And also the user id is there(user's id in user pool).Is there any way to get user attributes like(nick name,birthday,address) with these tokens or the with the user id in aws-cognito

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh it's straight forward with aws sdk CognitoIdentityServiceProvider class.Can use the same access token that we are getting from the user authentication

```
var params = {
    AccessToken:  "string"
};
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params, function(err, data) {
 if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
 } // an error occurred
 else{
    console.log(data);
 } // successful response
 })
```